How to disable table in ag-grid react
Have used the below code to disable the rows manually in ag-grid react.
cellStyle: { "pointer-events": "none", opacity: '0.4' }
applying the cellStyle for every columns in columnDefs.
Is there any option in ag-grid, to disable the whole table?
